# Counterpart of _start()

Tags: c, linux, windows

In `linux _start()` is the assembly function which triggers the `main()` function.

What's in Windows?
I am not sure whether my question is right or wrong?

Actually i am trying to use _start() in Linux - working fine.
But the same code in DevC++(windows)

> [Linker error] undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Comment: This MSDN blogpost is probably interesting to you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/03/6644060.aspx

Comment: In general, the "real" entrypoint is specified in the PE headers; the way to set it to a custom function depends from the linker used. What compiler/linker are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Windows use as entry point the function WinMain() which as the following declaration:

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, 
                     HINSTANCE hPreviousInstance, 
                     LPSTR lpszCmdLine, 
                     int nCmdShow);
```

I'm going try to explain you the basics of the `WinMain()`.

To understand what these `HINSTANCE` types mean, we have to resort to the analogy with files. When you open a file using a classic `syscall (open ())`, you get an integer value that is called the file descriptor. But in Microsoft's nomenclature, this is called a handle, or English. Most Windows API functions work with handles, and they are references to objects that you can use in Windows.

Handles are exactly like file descriptors. They are numeric values ​​that have no special meaning (they are not pointers to objects, for example) other than the value itself ...

For example: A process has a handle corresponding to its instance (`HINSTANCE`). Note that the same process can run more than once (you can open two windows from the same application - try Notepad, for example). So the "handle" of the instance being executed is passed to `WinMain` in `hInstance`, above ... The second "handle", hPreviousInstance, is merely historical ... In the Win16 API processes were placed in a list and handle to the previous instance of the application was reported in `hPreviousInstance` ... In Win32 onwards this argument will always get NULL (or 0).

Instead of getting a list of arguments (as with the argv array, in the main () function) our entry point is given a simple pointer to a string containing the command line. The `LPSTR` type can be understood as a "Long Pointer to STRing", ie a "char *" ... The term "long" here is also historical.

The fourth parameter is a constant that Windows sends to the application informing it of how the user wants the first window to be shown (or if it will be hidden initially!) ... Usually the constant used is `SW_SHOW`. And here's an explanation: Windows header files define a "tick" (universal measure of magnitude) of symbolic constants, many of which are bitmaps, that is, they can be "added" to others via the OR operator.

The `WinMain ()` function will return an integer value that should be 0 or a value from the `WM_QUIT` message (later I'll explain) ... That is, usually this value will be 0 and it has nothing to do with "`ERRORLEVEL`" has learned in DOS ... Windows does not deal with `ERRORLEVEL`.

Comment: The real entry point is in library code, which retrieves the values for the `WinMain` parameters and then calls your `WinMain` function.  Real entry point is typically named something like `_WinMainCRTStartup` but since the loader finds it using an entry in the PE header (as a comment says) its actual name is unimportant.